# Mapping Image id to Api object Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, api, mapping

I have a list of movies ids that match each individual image title id. I'm trying to map the image title to the right id and i'm having trouble figuring it out. Any ideas?

```
import "./MovieList.css";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


const MovieList = ({ list }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {list ? (
        <div className="list-container">
          <div>
            {list.map((m, idx) => {
              return <Link className="link" to={{pathname: '/details', state: {list}}}> <div key={idx}>
                  <img src={`/Images/${m.id}`} alt="poster"></img>
                  {m.title}
                  </div></Link>;
            })}{" "}
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        "loading..."
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default MovieList;
```

[image]

Comment: Could you, instead of pasting an image of your code, add code blocks? That makes helping a lot easier

Comment: added code block!

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? ' i'm having trouble figuring it out' does not really tell what you have tried and what exactly the issue is